# ODBC Pooling for IBM i V7

Tags: c#, sql, db2, odbc

Currently I am involved in developing an application using `C#.Net` which will communicate with IBM I (V7R1) using ODBC. The driver used is “`iSeries` Access `ODBC` Driver”. Pooling is enabled via the setting in “`ODBC` Data Source Administration” while `CPTimeout` set to 120.

I am looking into setting the following for that connection as well. `CheckConnectionOnOpen`=True 
`MinimumPoolSize`=25 
`MaximumPoolSize`=100 
`MaximumUseCount`=100

Could anyone specify how it can be set via `connectionstring` or otherwise.

Comment: why are you using ODBC driver instead of the [.NET managed provider](https://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/i/access/windows/dotnet.html)?

Comment: I thinnk you are just using IMB DB2.  See connectionstrings.com : https://www.connectionstrings.com/ibm-db2/

Comment: @Charles I am using that as well. but i want to know the full capabilities of the ODBC driver